# reference count of variable ios

Tags: iphone, ios, refer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the reference count of an NSObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640568/how-to-get-the-reference-count-of-an-nsobject)

Is there any way to find out reference count for individual variable at any given instance. I tried with heap shots it gives overall reference counts in a flow.

Thanks

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`-retainCount`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount) method to get the retain count for an `NSObject`, but bear in mind that you will almost certainly not get back any useful information. Objects can be retained by various parts of the system and frameworks so you will often get back unexpected results.

Comment: Apple has deprecated the method, because as you explained it will not supply any useful information.