# Swift: how to log out retain count of objects?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, reference, retain

Is there a way to quickly log out the retain count of objects to Xcode's Console?
If not, what's the next best alternative?

Comment: Why you need retainCount ?

Comment: Just as a teaching tool. I wanna show students how strong retain cycles happen, and just talk about the whole ARC thing.

Comment: Read these before using `retainCount` method. 
[10 (http://whentouseretaincount.com), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount), [3] (http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful), [5 Apple's explanation on retainCount method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount)

Comment: well it was never my intention to use `retainCount`.  I don't think it works in Swift in the first place, plus the docs say its not reliable. Just thought there'd be some simple way...

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way other than using XCode tools.

Comment: @sirab333 There is no difference between `retainCount` and `CFGetRetainCount()`.   A far better method of teaching about cycles is to use boxes and lines to draw the object graph;  the retain counts are meaningless.

Comment: We could lose the puritanism, guys. If he wants the retainCount, he wants the retainCount. Why he wants it is really none of your business. He wasn't asking for best memory management practices.

Answer (score 62):

using `CFGetRetainCount` function

Example:

```
// `CFGetRetainCount` is only available in the `Foundation` module
import Foundation

print(CFGetRetainCount(object))
```

Read more here : https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1521288-cfgetretaincount

hope helpful

Comment: Also note that in Swift, `CFRetainCount` also counts references of 'unknown' type, which could include weak references. I learned this by cross-referencing the runtime `CFGetRetainCount` value with the Xcode "View Memory Graph Hierarchy" tool. More here: https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2017/08/visual_memory_debugger.png

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would use instruments to get the retain count.  But as answered here the method is `retainCount`.

[How to get the reference count of an NSObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640568/how-to-get-the-reference-count-of-an-nsobject)

Comment: `retainCount` is no good in Swift. And otherwise - look at the docs under "Special Considerations": "This method is of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it..." How would you do it in Instruments?

Comment: Don't expect retainCount give you the exact values. Refer the links I attached to my comment (Question section)

Answer (score 1):

Other than using [`CFGetRetainCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1521288-cfgetretaincount) you can use [`_getRetainCount`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/71c62c04ace2b5b7f57caee012ecfe7ede280fe0/stdlib/public/core/DebuggerSupport.swift#L273) as well. The advantages of `_getRetainCount` are following:

1. `_getRetainCount` is available as part of Swift's standard library so you don't have to be dependant on `Foundation`.
2. On non-apple platforms `_getRetainCount` is the only choice as `CFGetRetainCount` is not available there.

Note that `_getRetainCount` provides total of strong, weak and unowned reference counts. If you only want strong reference count you can use [`_getUnownedRetainCount`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/71c62c04ace2b5b7f57caee012ecfe7ede280fe0/stdlib/public/core/DebuggerSupport.swift#L275) and [`_getWeakRetainCount`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/71c62c04ace2b5b7f57caee012ecfe7ede280fe0/stdlib/public/core/DebuggerSupport.swift#L277) to deduct.

As for practical use cases, the only use case I have for this is to write tests for catching retain cycles.

Answer (score -3):

```
print(_getRetainCount(objectName))
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55443712/edit) exppanation to your answer

Comment: class Dettol{
}
let d = Dettol()
print(_getRetainCount(d))